# Where Javascript get date, time from?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I am working on a clock that count down for my project, and I am curios about where Javascript get date and time from? From internet? From device? From browser?

```
        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: JavaScript will use the browser's time zone and display a date as text.

Answer (score 2):

It gets the current date & time (and by proxy, the UTC offset/locale) from the client's local environment. You can test this by changing your local clock.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an internet connection to use JavaScript. It gets the current date & time from the client's **local environment**.

> The **Date object** is a datatype in the JavaScript language. Most methods simply allow you to get and set the year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and millisecond fields of the object, using either local time or UTC (GMT, or universal) time.
>
> **The ECMAScript** standard requires the Date object to be able to represent any date and time, to millisecond precision, within 100 million days before or after 1/1/1970. This is a range of plus or minus 273,785 years, so JavaScript can represent date and time till the year 275755.

[Source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_date_object.htm)